# Firestore & SwiftUI - is my snapshot reader reading the db needlessly?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a project with firebase set up, and I have a function set up similarly to the sample from firebase, but the firebase document updates @Published vars in my observable object:

```
func getDataFromSession(env: GlobalEnvironmentObject) {
db.collection("sessions").document("firstSession")
    .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
      guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
        print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
        return
      }
      guard let data = document.data() else {
        print("Document data was empty.")
        return
      }
      print("Current data: \(data)")
      env.data1 = data[data1]
// env.data1 is the @Published bar data1
    }
}
```

and I'm calling this function in my swiftui view :

```
var body: some View {
  
        let fbConnection = FirebaseConnectionHandler(env: env)
        fbConnection.getDataFromSession()
```

When I run my app, my debug window is executing the print("Current data: (data)") line at lightning speed despite the fact that no values in the observable object/global environment have change. I was under the impression that the snapshot listener will only perform a read when data changes, and the swiftui views will only update when @Published properties change and so fare neither are happening (so it shouldn't be reading like crazy). And I'm not sure if it's performing a ton of reads in a row or if that output is normal (obv I only want it to read when there is a change in my document)...

What the heck am I doing wrong? How do I prevent the mega reads and have it so the data only reads when it is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out when I was writing my data to Firestore, all my data was being written to the same document. And, after searching the web, i learned that, when it comes to listeners in firestore, it is an all or nothing thing. So, my entire document was being called and updated, which triggered updates elsewhere, that would call and trigger, etc etc etc.

To fix, I took the document and split it into two documents, where one app can read to one but only write to the other, and the other app did vice versa (read to the other, write to the other). This way, the listener calls changes on a per document level and avoids the looping...

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Relax, you and the SDK are doing it nothing wrong. The very first read you are experiencing is due to the **initial state** of your data.

See the doc **View changes between snapshots** :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots

---

> Important: The first query snapshot contains added events for all
> existing documents that match the query. This is because you're
> getting a set of changes that bring your query snapshot current with
> the initial state of the query. This allows you, for instance, to
> directly populate your UI from the changes you receive in the first
> query snapshot, without needing to add special logic for handling the
> initial state.
>
> The initial state can come from the server directly, or from a local
> cache. If there is state available in a local cache, the query
> snapshot will be initially populated with the cached data, then
> updated with the server's data when the client has caught up with the
> server's state.

Comment: that makes no sense, because the terminal is just printing the same data over and over and over...when i remove the code to set my data from firebase equal to the observable object data, it seems to work fine...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out...if you are updating observable objects from firebase, put the listener object in your view (under "var body: some View {")...

Then, take any of the views in your struct (HStack, ZStack, etc) and add a .onAppear modifier, and call the function the updates your firebase from there...

Turns out the view keeps updating, but .onAppear will kick off the refreshing once...